# Why Estimated Execution Plan shows clustered index scan instead of table scan?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan, sql-server-2019

I have very simple table like this :

[image]

It contains only one clustered index on ID column (PRIMARY KEY) as you can see.
Data that are stored in that table :

[image]

When I do Display Estimated Execution Plan it shows me that it uses clustered index scan for following query :

[image]

I'm wondering why SQL engine shows me clustered index scan instead of table scan ?
I'm searching via **Name** column (not ID) and I assume that index does not contain any information about Name data (Name column) - the index is built based on ID column and should operate strictly on ID column if I understand it correctly.
So if I'm using **only** Name column which is not indexed - why it uses clustered index to search the table? I don't get it. I would expect table scan in this case.

Comment: Same thing basically: a table scan is a scan of a table which has no clustered index, in other words a heap. Obviously you want to index `Name` here

Comment: In SQL Server, the leaf level of the clustered index ***IS*** the table - all the data pages that make up the whole table. So a "clustered index scan" really is a table scan - it's just called differently